# I am getting "Please insert a disk into Removable Disk" when I insert my USB disk

Tags: windows-vista, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vista Pen drive error: Please insert disk into removable drive](https://superuser.com/questions/73754/vista-pen-drive-error-please-insert-disk-into-removable-drive)

Is there any way to fix this Problem. I am using Transcend 2GB JFV30 type flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

1)Please make use of this site “http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/online_recovery_2.asp?LangNo=0″

All the instruction are present how to repair your pen drive.

2) Download tool JetFlash Recovery Online from “http://www.transcendusa.com/support/dlcenter/ORT_Software.asp?Link=OnLineRecovery.exe”,

After browsing a lot I got this very good information.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I am the owner of this post. I was browsing through all over the net to find the solution of the problem. Finally I got the solution and I fixed the solution. Now my Flash drive is working fine.